# Receive explicit intent. Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to receive an explicit intent with the component option set?
Example:

```
Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.VIEW data=http://example.org flags=0x10000000 comp={com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity} }
```

The reason why i want to this this is because i want receive this intent above, launch another browser than the default one, and drop the intent before it starts the default browser. In another words, i want to make another browser the default one.

If this is impossible, any other ideas how i can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) You can explicitly launch alternative browser by calling something like `startActivity(new Intent(this, OtherBrowser.class))` from `Activity`.
2) You can't override the default browser, but you can provide a browser alternative that user could choose when opening `http://something`. Just have a look at `intent-filter`s that the default Browser declares (from Android sources).